# Node.js application volume problem with docker-compose

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, docker-compose

I have a Django + React Application that want to launch with docker-compose.
I have already started it locally with npx create-react-app.
It works fine if I run it with only that service:

```
docker-compose run --rm -p 3000:3000 frontend npm start
```

But it breaks if I run all together with:

```
docker-compose up
```

These are the logs:

```
betcomm-react |
betcomm-react | > frontend@0.1.0 start /app
betcomm-react | > react-scripts start
betcomm-react |
betcomm-react | ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.29.0.4/
betcomm-react | ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
betcomm-react | ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
betcomm-react | ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
betcomm-react | Starting the development server...
betcomm-react |
betcomm-react exited with code 0
```

What am I missing here ?

The project structure is

```
- backend
| - Dockerfile
| - Django Project
- frontend
| - node_modules
| - public
| - src
| - package.json
```

These are the Dockerfile and the docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  db:
    ... etc
  app:
    image: batcomm-django
    build: 
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: betcomm-django
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file:
      - .env.dev
  frontend:
    image: betcomm-react
    build: 
      context: ./frontend 
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: betcomm-react
    working_dir: /app
    command: "npm start"
    depends_on: 
      - app
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./frontend/:/app/
      - node-modules:/app/node_modules

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  node-modules:
```

**EDIT**
I have realized that calling the same Dockerfile with standalone docker causes the same break if I also add the volume to the /app folder. I want to add this volume so every change in the container gets changed in my host as well:

This works fine:

```
docker run -p 3001:3000 --rm -it betcomm-react-test /bin/sh
```

This breaks:

```
docker run -v frontend:/app -p 3001:3000 --rm -it betcomm-react-test /bin/sh

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /app/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-03-24T18_42_25_066Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Are you running docker via docker-machine on Mac OS?

Comment: The node_modules volume seems unnecessary, as there is already a directory named node_modules under ./frontend

Comment: I m running docker via docker-compose on MacOS

Comment: In every resource on the internet the volume on node_modules is given as necessary since you want not to syncronize that folder with your host. Apparently is called the node_modules volume trick: https://jdlm.info/articles/2016/03/06/lessons-building-node-app-docker.html @jizhilong